# SYSTEM process not having write privileges

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, perfmon

I'm running a process from the user SYSTEM. (In the Task Manager, the process is being run by the User Name SYSTEM, not my username.) Even though I'm an admin, the process can't write files over DFS because the username SYSTEM doesn't have the same permissions that I do. Since this refers to the local system, I don't know of any way of giving my local system write privileges over DFS...

Is this possible? The program I'm running is perfmon. Is it possible to make perfmon launch from my username, rather than the local system level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For system, you could grant permission for the computer account (COMPUTERNAME$) to the share/folder in question.

Comment: I'll try this now and accept the answer once checked, as this sounds like it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Hmm, I can't get this to work, and a similar question was posed which mentioned that computer accounts cannot be granted with shared access, only user accounts can. http://serverfault.com/questions/305265/grant-samba-share-permission-to-ad-computer-accounts

Comment: Computers are user accounts.  They have a username and password.  When you run code as local system, if it accesses network resources, it uses the COMPUTERNAME$ identity.