# Connect to Synology NAS with AD computer account

Tags: active-directory, network-share, synology

I need to access a Synology SMB shared folder with the use of a computer account.

I have joined the Synology to the domain, but I only see the user accounts and even adding Domain Computers to the share permissions I still have no access to the share.

Does Synology support this approach at all? I use DSM 7.1.1.

Comment: The question is crystal clear, I don't see any need to downvote or VTC it. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer. I suggest asking Synology support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grant Samba share permission to AD computer accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/305265/grant-samba-share-permission-to-ad-computer-accounts)